# Linux Mate: keepassxc icon is stretched disproportionally. How to fix?

Tags: mate-desktop, icons, mate-panel

I am running a Linux Mint with Mate window manager on board. For some reason, some of the icons in the tray are resized to fit the panel height, others are not. Weird thing is happening to the keepassxc icon that is rendered disproportionally stretched - an oval-shaped.

Can anybody give a suggestion how to tweak it so the icon shape is proper (be it small or big, but circle)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the mate notification area is that the apps control how the icons are displayed. So you either can modify the mate panel size (or minimum icon size) hoping there is a position it looks better or you create an issue at keepassxc.
Eventually I would migrate to ayatana indicators using the mate-indicator-applet. They are also used in Ubuntu MATE. Setting them up yourself is maybe not that easy.

Comment: Thank you! I think i will file an issue for keepassxc.